# How can I keep items checked in a recyclerView when scrolling

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have a recyclerview where user can hold to enable selection and by clicking in each item they get checked (imageView with a check icon), the problem I am having is that for the nature of a recyclerview when user scroll too far off screen that check is lost, I mean, item is still checked but the check is not visible so user might think they need to click again, I am looking for a way to preserve that imageview (checked icon) no matter how far user scroll up or down.

This below is the onBindViewHolder and the ClickItem method.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Expense expense = expenses.get(position);

    ExpenseViewHolder vaultItemHolder = (ExpenseViewHolder) holder;

    vaultItemHolder.item.setText("" + expense.getItem());
    vaultItemHolder.category.setText("" + expense.getCategory());
    vaultItemHolder.date.setText("" + expense.getDate());
    vaultItemHolder.amount.setText("$ " + formatNumberCurrency(String.valueOf(expense.getAmount())));
    vaultItemHolder.type.setText(expense.getType());

    vaultItemHolder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {

        // check condition
        if (!isEnable) {

            // when action mode is not enable
            // initialize action mode
            ActionMode.Callback callback = new ActionMode.Callback() {
                @Override
                public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

                    // initialize selection_menu inflater
                    MenuInflater menuInflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                    // inflate selection_menu
                    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.selection_menu, menu);
                    // return true
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

                    // when action mode is prepare
                    // set isEnable true
                    isEnable = true;
                    // create method

                    ClickItem(vaultItemHolder);
                    // set observer on getText method
                    mainViewModel.getText().observe((LifecycleOwner) activity
                            , s -> {

                                // when text change
                                // set text on action mode title
                                mode.setTitle(String.format(activity.getString(R.string.selected), s));

                            });

                    // return true
                    return true;

                }

                public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem menuItem) {

                    // when click on action mode item
                    // get item  id
                    int id = menuItem.getItemId();

                    // use switch condition
                    switch (id) {

                        case R.id.menu_duplicate:

                            //firebase base code to duplicate

                            // finish action mode
                            mode.finish();

                            break;

                        case R.id.menu_delete:

            //firebase code for deletion

                            // finish action mode
                            mode.finish();

                            break;

                        case R.id.menu_select_all:

                            // when click on select all

                            // check condition
                            if (selectedExpenses.size() == expenses.size()) {

                                // when all item selected
                                // set isSelectall false
                                isSelectAll = false;

                                // create select array list
                                selectedExpenses.clear();

                            } else {

                                // when  all item unselected
                                // set isSelectALL true
                                isSelectAll = true;

                                // clear select array list
                                selectedExpenses.clear();

                                // add value in select array list
                                selectedExpenses.addAll(expenses);

                            }

                            // set text on view model
                            mainViewModel.setText(String.valueOf(selectedExpenses.size()));

                            // notify adapter
                            notifyDataSetChanged();

                            break;
                    }

                    // return true
                    return true;

                }

                @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
                @Override
                public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

                    // when action mode is destroy
                    // set isEnable false
                    isEnable = false;

                    // set isSelectAll false
                    isSelectAll = false;

                    // clear select array list
                    selectedExpenses.clear();

                    // notify adapter
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

            };

            // start action mode
            ((AppCompatActivity) v.getContext()).startActionMode(callback);

        } else {

            // when action mode is already enable
            // call method
            ClickItem(vaultItemHolder);

        }

        // return true
        return true;

    });
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        // check condition
        if (isEnable) {
            // when action mode is enable
            ClickItem(vaultItemHolder);

        } else {
            // when action mode is not enable edit single item
            item = expense.getItem();
            category = expense.getCategory();
            date = expense.getDate();
            postId = expense.getId();
            amount = expense.getAmount();
            type = expense.getType();

            updateExpense();

        }
    });

    // check condition
    if (isSelectAll) {
        // when value selected
        // visible all check box image
        vaultItemHolder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {
        // when all value unselected
        // hide all check box image
        vaultItemHolder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
}
```

**ClickItem method**

private void ClickItem(ExpenseViewHolder holder) {

```
    // get selected item value
    Expense s = expenses.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());

    // check condition
    if (holder.checkbox.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {

        // when item not selected
        // visible check box image
        holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // add value in select arrayList
        selectedExpenses.add(s);

    } else {
        // when item selected
        // hide check box image

        holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // remove value from select arrayList
        selectedExpenses.remove(s);
    }

    // set text on view model
    mainViewModel.setText(String.valueOf(selectedExpenses.size()));

}
```

Comment: Create a variable like `checkBoxChecked` in the data class of the `expenses` list. When the box is checked, update the value in the list. And set its value in the `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166) might help in terms of checking and unchecking elements in a RecylerView.